# Affiliation of author in achemso class

Tags: titles, achemso

I use the achemso class in order to write a scientific article. I have to set author and their affiliation with `affiliation` or `altaffiliation` commands. Here is a short example :

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{lab 1}
\author{Author 2}
\email{author@lab}
\author{Author 3}
\author{Author 4}
\affiliation{lab 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

output :

[image]

I would like `author 1` to belong to `lab 1` and `lab 2` and other author to belong only to `lab 2`. But it does not work. With the above example `author 1` belongs only to `lab 1`.

If I add an `\altaffiliation` command for `lab 2` just after `author 1` it works but `lab 2` appears two times at the bottom of the page.

[image]

How can I avoid that achemso write two times the same affiliation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `\alsoaffiliation` command, which deals with this case:

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{lab 1}
\alsoaffiliation{lab 2}
\author{Author 2}
\email{author@lab}
\author{Author 3}
\author{Author 4}
\affiliation{lab 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

`\altaffiliation` is intended for the case where you have a specific note or similar for one or more authors, whereas `\alsoaffiliation` is used for 'standard' affiliations which are shared in some way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not find this in the doc. Nevertheless, for me its a kind of magic ! How does latex know that the contains of `\alsoaffiliation` and `\affiliation` refer to `lab 2` ?

Comment: Actually it does not work with accentuated letters, such as université in france. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @Ger It should do: please either post a new question about this or update the example here.